# R fails to encode romainan characters with UTF-8 correctly

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm working on a dataset of locations where some location names use local characters. Most characters are viewed correctly, but I'm having issues with some Romanian characters, like for example "ș".

I have tried changing my Windows 10 64 bit system locale to use UTF-8 encoding, but that did not solve the issue.

A sample file can be found here for testing: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T7QQQ7G_dA_rXD9Ewf51uuQ6CUkscjP_/view?usp=sharing

This line imports the data:

```
df <- read.delim("R_Encode_Issue.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", encoding = "UTF-8", colClasses=c("character","character","character"))

> df
  region country         chapter
1 Europe Moldova Chi<U+0219>inau
```

This displays the location chapter as "Chiinau" (Stackoverflow can't displays this even :D) both in the console and in the viewer.

If I convert the data_table to a tibble:

```
df2 <- as_tibble(df)

> df2
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  region country chapter 
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
1 Europe Moldova Chișinău
```

The console displays the location chapter as "Chișinău" but the viewer as "Chiinau".

I write the data to a .csv file:

```
write.csv(df2, file = "R_Encode_Out.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

And the location chapter is written as "Chiinau" in the written file.

R version:

```
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.3                         
year           2019                        
month          03                          
day            11                          
svn rev        76217                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
nickname       Great Truth
```

RStudio version:

```
$mode
[1] "desktop"

$version
[1] ‘1.1.463’
```

I expected the viewer, or at least the written file to display the characters correctly, when I use UTF-8 as the encoding on import and export. But the case is that the characters are exported incorrectly.

Any insight on what I can do to correct this?

Comment: Try `write_csv()` from the package `readr` instead of R's inbuilt `write.csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different import and export functions than base R. I got this to work using `readr` in the exported file (it seems that viewer does display it as `Chi<U+0219>inau`. The exported file opens correctly in notepad, and in Excel if I specify that it has UTF-8 encoding.

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("C:/Users/Andrew/Downloads/R_Encode_Issue.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))

df
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  region country chapter 
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   
1 Europe Moldova Chișinău

write_csv(df, "C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/R_Encode_Issue.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, the readr export function seemed to do the trick! Thanks for your input :)